# Play Framework fetch(int max) vs limit

Tags: jpa, playframework

I am using Play Framework 1.2.4. In model classes we have find methods with many options. For instance:

```
List<Cat> cats = Cat.find("query").fetch();
```

or we can set a max results like:

```
List<Cat> cats = Cat.find("query").fetch(50);
```

Is this the equivalent of

```
SELECT * from cat LIMIT 50;
```

I just would like to make sure that in terms of performance they are at least same? If not what is *the best* way of getting last `n records` in Play Framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fetch(50)` internally uses `javax.persistence.Query.setMaxResults`. This will then be translated by Hibernate into `LIMIT` or `TOP`, depending on the DB dialect. So, in terms of performance, they are the same.

So to fetch the newest *n* cats,

```
List<Cat> cats = Cat.find("order by age").fetch(50);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. It was what I expected but needed to make sure..